# Spring MVC + EntityManger - Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to acces my database using EntityManager class but I have error when I try to deploy my project to Tomcat.

**This is my DAO calss:**

```
package ninja.majewski.newcats.application;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ninja.majewski.newcats.domain.Cat;

package ninja.majewski.newcats.application;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ninja.majewski.newcats.domain.Cat;

@Repository
public class CatsDAO {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Connection conn;

    private ArrayList<Cat> cats;

    public CatsDAO() {
        cats = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void readDataFromDb() {
        cats.clear();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM catstable";
        conn = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                Float weight = rs.getFloat("weight");
                String owner = rs.getString("owner");
                cats.add(new Cat(name, weight, owner));
            }

            rs.close();
            ps.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    public void addCat(Cat c) {
        cats.add(c);

//      String sql = "INSERT INTO catstable(name, weight, owner) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
//      conn = null;
//      
//      try {
//          conn = dataSource.getConnection();
//          PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
//          ps.setString(1, c.getName());
//          ps.setFloat(2, c.getWeight());
//          ps.setString(3, c.getOwner());
//
//          ps.executeUpdate(); 
//          
//          ps.close();
//      }
//      catch(SQLException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      finally {
//          closeConnection();
//      }

        entityManager.merge(c);
    }

    public void removeCat(String name) {
        for(int i = 0; i < cats.size(); i++) {
            if(cats.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
                cats.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        String sql = "DELETE FROM WHERE name = ?";
        conn = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.executeUpdate();

            ps.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    public Cat getCatById(Integer id) {
        return cats.get(id);
    }

    public ArrayList<Cat> getCats() {
        readDataFromDb();

        return cats;
    }

    private void closeConnection() {
        if(conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My applicationContext.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ninja.majewski" />

    <context:annotation-config />


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cats" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="entityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ninja.majewski" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**My pom.xml file:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ninja.majewski.newcats</groupId>
    <artifactId>NewCatsProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>NewCatsProject-domain</module>
        <module>NewCatsProject-application</module>
        <module>NewCatsProject-webapp</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**And my errors:**

```
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:NewCatsProject-webapp' did not find a matching property.
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 1 2015 22:30:46 UTC
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.30.0
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows XP
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            5.1
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             D:\aplikacje\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b15
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Documents and Settings\KM\Pulpit\KursFroWom\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Documents and Settings\KM\Pulpit\KursFroWom\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Documents and Settings\KM\Pulpit\KursFroWom\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\endorsed
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250
gru 26, 2015 10:56:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:\aplikacje\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;D:/Aplikacje/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin/client;D:/Aplikacje/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin;D:/Aplikacje/Java/jre1.8.0_65/lib/i386;D:\Aplikacje\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Dane aplikacji\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\Aplikacje\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin;D:\Aplikacje\Borland\CBUILD~1\Projects\Bpl;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem;C:\PROGRAM FILES\QUICKTIME\QTSYSTEM;D:\Aplikacje\Internet Explorer;C:\xampp\mysql\lib;D:\aplikacje\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;D:\TDM-GCC-32\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;D:\Aplikacje\MATLAB\R2011a\runtime\win32;D:\Aplikacje\MATLAB\R2011a\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\KM\Pulpit\eclipseEE\eclipse;;.
gru 26, 2015 10:56:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
gru 26, 2015 10:56:52 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
gru 26, 2015 10:56:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
gru 26, 2015 10:56:52 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
gru 26, 2015 10:56:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1735 ms
gru 26, 2015 10:56:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
gru 26, 2015 10:56:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
gru 26, 2015 10:56:56 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
gru 26, 2015 10:56:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
gru 26, 2015 10:56:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
gru 26, 2015 10:56:56 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
gru 26, 2015 10:56:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Dec 26 10:56:57 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
gru 26, 2015 10:56:57 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
gru 26, 2015 10:56:58 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
gru 26, 2015 10:56:58 AM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
gru 26, 2015 10:56:58 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
gru 26, 2015 10:56:58 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<clinit>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:100)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 35 more

gru 26, 2015 10:56:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<clinit>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:100)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 35 more

gru 26, 2015 10:56:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
gru 26, 2015 10:56:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/NewCatsProject-webapp] startup failed due to previous errors
gru 26, 2015 10:56:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
gru 26, 2015 10:56:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
gru 26, 2015 10:56:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
gru 26, 2015 10:56:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6346 ms
gru 26, 2015 10:57:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
gru 26, 2015 10:57:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
gru 26, 2015 10:57:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
gru 26, 2015 10:57:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
gru 26, 2015 10:57:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
gru 26, 2015 10:57:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
gru 26, 2015 10:57:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
gru 26, 2015 10:57:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA, `EntityManager` is part of it, is an abstraction layer on top of simple `JDBC` and is responsible for handling Object/Relational Mapping stuff. I recommend to use either `JDBC` API or `JPA`, not both of them simultaneously, like you did in your sample. And about your problem, it will be solved if you add `JTA` dependency in your classpath:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And rename your bean id from `entityManager` to `entityManagerFactory`

Comment: I added this dependecy and now I am getting this error: "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined" ....